# How do I ensure programs ask for permission to access the internet?

Tags: linux

I am just beginning to use Debian 7 which happens to be my first ever Linux OS. I chose the default installation for Debian 7. It came with Gnome (gdm3) desktop and a lot of programs.

Below are my questions:

1. What command(s) do I type to find out what programs are accessing the internet at any given moment in time?
2. Do programs that are installed by default ask for permission from me to access the internet?
3. How do I ensure that ALL programs have to ask for my permission first before accessing the internet?

Comment: 1. `iftop`, `lsof`. 2. No. 3. By launching via `unshare -n `.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Thanks for the reply. I checked out 'unshare -n' on http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?unshare+2. That webpage does not say anything about the 'n' parameter. What does the parameter do?

Comment: Use `man unshare` to learn more.

Comment: @DeerHunter: I suppose another way to ensure ALL programs ask for my permission first is to configure iptables in Debian?

Comment: Check this question on Unix & Linux SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process

Comment: @DeerHunter Could you post this info as an answer to get this question off of the "unanswered" section?